# Catch onDownload event for browser pdf viewer

Tags: angular, pdf

I have an object tag that display a pdf file:

```
<object [data]="pdfData" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px"></object>
```

Then I get the pdf file from server and set to pdfData:

```
this.service.getDataPdf().subscribe(res => {
  const file = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsDataUrl(res);
  fileReader.onloadend(() => {
     this.pdfData = this.domSanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(fileReader.result);
  });
});
```

Everything works perfectly, but I need to do extra stuff when user click on download icon. Is there a way to catch the download event in the pdf viewer? I noticed the pdf is embedded inside an  tag and there seems to be no way to control it.

Comment: @KJ what about the default name when user click on download? Let's say I need to set the default name to something else, Chrome is always set it to download.pdf

Comment: I need to catch the download event first in order to create an anchor tag and then customize the download file name